# How to correctly parse dates and without warnings in a tibble?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, warnings, lubridate

reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- tibble(
  dates = c("43755", "43757", "22/12/2020", "20/12/2020")
)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    dates = case_when(
      str_detect(dates, "/.*/") ~ dmy(dates),
      str_detect(dates, "[0-9]{5}") ~ as_date(as.numeric(dates), origin = as.Date("1900-01-01")) - 2,
      TRUE ~ NA_Date_
    )
  )
```

output: ok

```
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  dates     
  <date>    
1 2019-10-17
2 2019-10-19
3 2020-12-22
4 2020-12-20
```

```
Warning messages:

1: Problem with `mutate()` input `dates`.
i  2 failed to parse.
i Input `dates` is `case_when(...)`. 
2: Problem with `mutate()` input `dates`.
i NAs introducidos por coerción
i Input `dates` is `case_when(...)`.
```

The output is ok but the warnings are telling me something maybe I don't know. How to get rid of the warnings (if appropiate)?

Comment: You are getting warnings because `"43755"` can’t be parsed by `dmy()`, and because `as.numeric()` fails for `"22/12/2020"`. You’re not using the *results* of these calculations but you are still computing them. Unfortunately there isn’t really a good solution for this using `case_when`. The best solution is to do the test element-wise.

Answer (score 1):

this `data.table` approach seems to work... i think?

```
library(data.table)
library(openxlsx)

#slghtly altered sample data
df <- tibble(
  dates = c("43755", "43757", "22/12/2020", "20/12/2020", "2020-02-03")
)

setDT(df)
df[, date2 := fcase(
  grepl( "/.*/", dates ), as.Date( dates, format = "%d/%m/%Y" ),
  grepl( "[0-9]{5}", dates ), suppressWarnings(openxlsx::convertToDate( dates )),
  default = NA ) ][]
```